# item is getting out of the border of the form when using larger screen

Tags: c#, winforms

I made this project with a fixed 1370 width resolution screen in mind. However, when I open the program on other displays (such as a 1056 width), all controls will go out of the screen boundaries due to lesser available space.

How do I make the controls use the same layout structure even on smaller screens?

[image]

Comment: Check out this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/842418/Designing-the-Layout-of-Windows-Forms-using-a

Comment: Unless it's a fixed size form, **you should never** set the size of controls to a fixed height/width *specially when designing on a larger display*. Two control properties can help you with this, which are [`Anchor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.anchor(v=vs.110).aspx), and [`Dock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Using these two with *(or without, depending on your needs)* some [`TableLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)s should give you full control over the locations/sizes of your controls, which is explained very well in the link posted by @4D1C70. Some other controls like [`FlowLayoutPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) & [`SplitContainer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx) can be helpful in some cases.

Comment: Deciding on the minimum screen size you want to support is critical.  Design the UI with that size.  Scaling up is easy, scaling down never is.  You can still limp along with AutoScroll = True, but nobody likes it.

Answer (score 0):

use the `anchor` property of the container and set it to right. this way the distance between the container and the right border of the form will always remain the same